# Get values that are repeated in a range two times or more in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple columns of ticker names in the range `A2:D` like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **ticker1** | **ticker2** | **ticker3** | **ticker4** |
| AAPL | *BA* | AMZN | *BA* |
| *BA* | DAL | AMD | *F* |
| COST | *F* |  | Z |

The goal is to return cells that appear twice (in two different columns), and separately, to return cells if appears thrice (in three different columns), like this:

| F | G |
| --- | --- |
| **repeated two times or more** | **repeated three times or more** |
| BA | BA |
| F |  |

I have a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PvGWPsBZ3NsqlVWVlmJaoP5kPKc01KM8knOSYMdU2dM/edit?usp=sharing) with sample columns and desired results.

I have tried the following formulas, but I cannot figure out how to search across all possibilities.

`=IF(COUNTIF($B:$E, $A2:$A20)>0, $A2:$A20, "")`: returns only one match from the first column

`=VLOOKUP($A2:$A20, $B2:$E50, 1, true)`: returns only one match as well and the data isn't sorted. If I use `false` instead of `true` I get no results.

`=QUERY($A2:$E50, "select A where A matches B:E label A 'Multis'", 0)`: only returns results if they are in the same row, i.e., when A3 matches C3, but not when A3 matches C4.

None of these formula can see if column B matches column C. If I could get any of these to work I could nest searches `A→B:E`, `B→C:E`, `C→D:E` and `D→E`, and then combine the results and delete repeats. I have not been able to get the `A→B:E` to work correctly.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried directly in the question and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 8 times.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not really matter whether the repeated values are in *different columns*, you can do this with `filter(countif())` and `flatten()` like this:

`=unique( filter( flatten(A2:D4), countif(A2:D4, flatten(A2:D4)) >= 2 ) )`

`=unique( filter( flatten(A2:D4), countif(A2:D4, flatten(A2:D4)) >= 3 ) )`

If you want the result be sorted, wrap these formulas in `sort()`.